# Can I use tasker to turn LTE/4G mode on/off on my Droid Bionic?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, tasker, motorola-droid-bionic

I'd like to turn LTE on while I'm at work and off at home; I have the appropriate profiles, but I can't find an appropriate action.   Is this something that could be done with an intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping the "Wimax" or "Mobile Data 2G/3G" Net Actions would be what you need, but after looking around it doesn't look like Tasker supports 4G on/off switching. Per [Tasker forum user Pent](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/tasker/uUSxFYxetQE/discussion) regarding this issue (on a different phone):

> > If this isn't currently a feature is there any way to implement it?
>
> It isn't and there's no 'official' way to implement it. I was hoping
>   there would be something in ICS, but don't think there is after a
>   quick scan.
>
> One day I'll have to do some research, but I prefer working on
>   features that will still work going forwards and benefit everyone.
>
> Pent

Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Thanks.   I found [this writeup](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/detecting-and-using-lte-networks/) on the Motorolo dev site that talks about how to detect the network type, but I found no sign of an API that would let you change the preference, so there's probably no way for Tasker to implement it.  :-(

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just go to settings then wireless and networks then mobile networks and change it from both 4G LTE/CDMA to just CDMA when you get off work? Problem solved, check it out.

Comment: The point of apps like Tasker is to automate tasks like what you describe. You can't do anything with Tasker you couldn't already do manually. So, your answer isn't really an answer.

Comment: Gina, that's what I've been doing, but @Al Everett is exactly right; I was hoping that Tasker could take care of it for me.